# Need to read Excel spreadsheets, store in Oracle DB using PHP, to view in EXTJS Grouping grid

Tags: php, json, extjs, phpexcel

I have a PHP parser using PHPExcel that reads in a Excel file and stores the contents into an Oracle database.

The problem is that the parser reads every line and does not set up any distinction between headers of rows and the data contained within those rows.  When the info is read from the database it is read in a flat file listing and is not easy to navigate.

I am currently reading the data into an EXTJS Grid. I would like to be able to read the Excel, store it in the DB, then pull it out and view it in a new EXTJS GroupingGrid, where the group would be the 'header' for each worksheet in the Excel file.

Has anyone ever used PHPExcel or know how to use PHPExcel to read the Excel file and output the header (1,1) in each worksheet, so that I can store it in the database and pull it out and show it in the JSON so the groupingGrid will give me the ability to have a plus sign for each header so that I can click the plus sign and view all the contents under that header within the grid?

Answer (score 0):

Hy, you can use this php-excell-reader http://code.google.com/p/php-excel-reader/ . I'm using it and works perfect. You can manipulate every cell of every row.

1. Count the cells
2. Count the rows
3. Make a loop to that count and manipulate data (you can add +1 if you want to skip
   first row or first cell.

Answer (score 0):

```
//  Include the PHPExcel library
require_once './Classes/PHPExcel.php';
//  Load the Excel File
$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel5');
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load("myExcelFile.xls");
//  Loop through every worksheet
foreach ($objPHPExcel->getWorksheetIterator() as $worksheet) {
   //  Read the value at Cell A1 in the current worksheet
   $cellValue = $worksheet->getCell('A1')->getValue();
   //  Do whatever you want with $cellValue
   //  Store it in a database
   //  Whatever...
}
```

of course, you might want a bit of error handling in there as well, in case myExcelFile.xls doesn't exist, or you don't have read permissions, or isn't really an Excel file, but just wrap it in a try/catch block and handle as you wish.

You can also set up a read filter if you only want to load the first line of each worksheet rather than every single row and column:

```
//  Include the PHPExcel library
require_once './Classes/PHPExcel.php';

/**  Define a Read Filter class implementing PHPExcel_Reader_IReadFilter  */
class firstRowFilter implements PHPExcel_Reader_IReadFilter
{
    public function readCell($column, $row, $worksheetName = '') {
        //  Only read the heading row
        return ($row == 1);
}

//  Create an instance of our Read Filter
$firstRowFilter = new firstRowFilter();

//  Instantiate the correct Reader
$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel5');
//  Tell the Reader only to load cells that match our Read Filter
$objReader->setReadFilter($firstRowFilter)
//  Load the Excel File
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load("myExcelFile.xls");
//  Loop through every worksheet
foreach ($objPHPExcel->getWorksheetIterator() as $worksheet) {
   //  Read the value at Cell A1 in the current worksheet
   $cellValue = $worksheet->getCell('A1')->getValue();
   //  Do whatever you want with $cellValue
   //  Store it in a database
   //  Whatever...
}
```